# Bash running in sequence from Cronjob

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script
sleep 15 & wait
python pythonFileName.py & wait
python pythonFileName.py & wait
python pythonFileName.py & wait
```

How do I get it to wait for the previous line to finish executing before moving to the next?

It work fine when you call the bash file directly , but when called from **cronjob**, it's executing everything without waiting for the previous one to finish.

Sleep works fine with this but for the py file, it's executing without waiting. 
I also tried the following

```
A; B    Run A and then B, regardless of success of A
A && B  Run B if A succeeded
A || B  Run B if A failed
A &     Run A in background.
```

Comment: The `& wait` should be harmless per se, but you will simplify enormously by taking them out. Probably the problem is elsewhere, and the symptom is that the job finishes quickly because it doesn't get the input you expect, perhaps because of a permissions problem.

Comment: Expanding on triplee's comment: `&` means "don't wait for this to finish before going on", but the `wait` means "actually, *do* wait for that to finish". Basically, they cancel each other out and are therefore not doing anything useful.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Hmm.... I tried removing &, same issue.

Comment: @FlyingAtom Then there must be something about the scripts that's causing it, like they might be dropping into the background (essentially like `&`ing themselves). Or something. Impossible to tell for sure without knowing more about the scripts.

Comment: @GordonDavisson http://pastebin.com/JEsNSh5w , The scripts, does this kind of stuff happen even though it runs perfectly fine without  cronjob? It's a python file

Comment: @FlyingAtom Hmm, I don't see anything too weird. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure `python` is in the path when running from cron?  It's often the case that your cron job's environment is stripped down compared to your normal shell environment since it doesn't execute the normal environment setup scripts.  Does it work if you specify the full path to `python`?